# Unit Testing UICollectionView.indexPath(for: UICollectionViewCell)

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uikit, collectionview

I am trying to unit test this bit of code in a `ViewController`

```
    func categoryTextEditedAt(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, _ text: String) {
        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell), text != "" else {return}

        //Rest of the codes to be tested
    }
```

And in my Unit Test to test the above function is as follows:

```
    func testCategoryTextEditedAt() {
        sut.viewDidLoad()
        sut.collectionView.reloadData()
        let cell = sut.collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(sut.collectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
        sut.categoryTextEditedAt(cell!, "testString")
    }
```

but I am keep getting 'nil' for the `indexPath` inside `categoryTextEditedAt(:)` function. As I debug, I found that inside `testCategoryTextEditedAt()` cell has a value but `self.collectionView.indexPath(for:cell)` keeps returning 'nil' for 'indexPath.'

How can I go about this process?

Comment: Have you provided the data source for the collection view in your test?

Comment: Yes I did in the init part of the test.

Comment: Where do you add the code of `sut.collectionView.dataSource = ...`?

Comment: it is provided from the userDefault -> Model -> sut. As I mentioned above, cell is not nil. If I print cell, it is printing as follows = "Optional(<XXX.CategoryCell: 0x7f8633c6f800; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600001ea2360>>)"

Comment: But if you know other approach to provide dataSource inside testing function I am happy to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are curious how to unit test collectionViewDelegateMethod:

```
    func categoryTextEditedAt(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, _ text: String) {
        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell), text != "" else {return}

        //Rest of the codes to be tested
    }
```

you can do something like

```
func testCategoryTextEditedAt() {
    class MockCV: UICollectionView {
        override func indexPath(for cell: UICollectionViewCell) -> IndexPath? {
            let anyIndexPathWhichEverYoulike = IndexPath(item:0, section:0)
            return anyIndexPathWhichEverYoulike
        }
    }
    sut.collectionView = MockCV()
    let cell = sut.collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(sut.collectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
    sut.categoryTextEditedAt(cell!, "testString")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your issue is because you are trying to test code in the wrong place.

Imagine if you have to test a unit function you need to instantiate all `UICollection` struct, it is a bad smell.

For example, you can do this.

```
enum UseCaseError {
    textEmpty
}

class UseCase {
    private let index: Int
    private let text: String
    init(index: Int, text: String) {
        self.index = index
        self.text = text
    }

    public func execute() throws {
        guard text.isEmpty == false else {
            throw UseCaseError.textEmpty
        }

        // your logic here to be tested
    }
}
```

Looking at this `UseCase`, you can test when `text` is empty and all your business logic

Now you just have to put it into `categoryTextEditedAt` method

```
func categoryTextEditedAt(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, _ text: String) {
    guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) { return }
    try? UseCase(index: indexPath.item, text: text).execute()
}
```

If you put the code separated you could test it before, and you don't need to waste time trying to make `UIKit` functions work, just your logic.

I hope to help you with this example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this can be an alternative to my approach but I hope to minimize the introduction of new class just for the cause of unit testing.

Comment: Normally, collectionView CellFotItem or didSelect or any other delegate and datasource methods can be tested using dependency injection or mocking

Comment: I hope you find a solution which suits better for your case